# What's the advantage in purchasing new hosting purely for 301 redirections

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect, multiple-domains

As a follow on from [How do I adjust our "default" domain](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21346/how-do-i-adjust-our-default-domain) I am about to setup 301 redirections from a selection of TLD to our recently selected default domain.

Currently ALL of our TLDs point to the same IP, a single host, and I had initially thought to setup the 301s on this hosting. In comments by @ThomasClayson in the above linked question, he suggests purchasing new hosting purely for the 301 redirects.

What would be the advantage to us in purchasing new hosting purely for the 301 redirections? Why not redirect on the same host? (Or does this not work!?)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to buy an additional hosting account.  All you need is a 301 from the old URL to your new URL.  Having the new URL on a separate IP OR separate host gives you no additional value.

All it will create is an additional headache for managing your accounts because you will never want to shut down your old URL (it will always do a 301 redirect).  People will continue to go to your old URL for years and depending on the reasons you have for changing domains, you might need to keep the old one forever for legal, trademark, or intellectual property reasons.  Even if you plan on completely shutting off the old URL one day (even the 301's) there is no reason for 2 hosting accounts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need for a new hosting. If you are using one of the most popular hosting (I think the not popular one have this possibility too), you'll be able to setup the redirect to your new domain. Besides, there's no advantage in purchasing a new hosting plan.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry dude, I work with a dedicated servers, so creating a new hosting account is of no concequence to me.

Normally on hosting accounts you can add a domain to your hosting and point it to a directory off your main directory. This will have the same effect.

Just remember to set your robots.txt so that robots don't go there, and your .htaccess on the main directory to block access to it, then you can add the 301 redirects into the new domain folder.

Oh and btw its ThomasClayson, with an s. :p