# Preserve search engine rankings while shifting to new domain name

Tags: seo, domains, search-engines, search-engine-indexing, ranking

We have to shift our web-site to a new domain due to some unavoidable circumstances. The portal has been up and running there since 2009.  It has good index in various search engines and we are getting a good number of page hits on daily basis.

Losing the search hits and index are our big concern. We are not sure how best we can handle this.

What all can be done to preserve as much as possible while shifting to new domain name.

Comment: Please, read my answer to this similar discussion: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21346/how-do-i-adjust-our-default-domain/21452#21452

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa thanks for the quick reply and i read answer its really very helpful.since we are permanently moving to new domain so how much can be restored in all these efforts as i also need to make an analysis report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're set up in Google's Webmaster Tools, you can explicitly tell them you're switching domains with the [change of address utility](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=83106) on top of the usual 301 redirect stuff.

Answer (score 1):

**301 Redirect Old Pages to New Pages**: Setting up a 301 Redirect will not only send the user to the correct page, but will also tell search engines that the page has been permanently been moved and it will transfer the link credit to the new page. Ideally, this should be done at page level: Each page of the old site should be redirected to the new site's equivalent url, mapping old-page to new-page.

**Use the [Change of Address Tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en)** in Google Search Console (the rebranded name for Google Webmaster Tools), as mentioned in Su's post.

Bing has a similar [Site Move](http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/how-to-use-the-site-move-tool-bb8f5112) tool, so use it too.

**Update any important Backlinks** where possible to point to the new site - use a backlink checker tool to find them