# How to do a 301 redirect in DirectAdmin & WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, 301-redirect, control-panel

In the past, our company had only one domain (`www.domain_old.com`) which obviously was the main domain. Now we have bought a new domain (`www.domain_new.com`), which we'd like to be the main domain from now on (i.e., for all the webpages, subdomains, emails, etc...). In other words:

> www.domain_old.com --> www.domain_new.com

Answers to similar questions on this site suggest using a `301` redirect, so I assume that's the best option.

Our website uses DirectAdmin and WordPress; how can I add a `301` redirect for the *old_domain* to the *new_domain* using these?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set 301 redirect in wordpress .htacces file](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25840/how-to-set-301-redirect-in-wordpress-htacces-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [forum on the DirectAdmin website](http://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=1176) where they tell you how to edit the *.htaccess* file through DirectAdmin:

> You can edit it through the Filemanager in DA, you'd just have to type it in manually. ex:
>
> `http://domain.com:2222/CMD_FILE_MANAGER/domains/domain.com/public_html/.htaccess?action=edit`

Once you can edit your *.htaccess* file you can add a redirect:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain-new\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain-new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```